# Saving intermediate layer weights, when large amount of data is feed via generator?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

```
img_width, img_height = 299, 299
batch_size = 6
epochs = 1
classes = 12



train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function = preprocess)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
train_data_dir,
target_size = (img_height, img_width),
batch_size = batch_size, 
class_mode = 'categorical')


base_model = Xception(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
x =base_model.predict_generator(train_generator, steps=None,
                        max_queue_size=10, workers=1,
                        use_multiprocessing=False, verbose=0)
```

The problem with this method is that x is forced to hold all the weights of batches during runtime, and it ultimately crashes my system due to memory issues.
So I can't save it to `.npy. file

Is there a way to save weights every batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible in the following way:

```
import math

number_of_examples = len(train_generator.filenames) # number of images
number_of_generator_steps = math.ceil(number_of_examples / (1.0 * batch_size))

current_iteration = 0
for x, _ in train_generator:
    prediction = model.predict(x)
    # here comes your custom saving function.
    current_iteration += 1
    if current_iteration == number_of_generator_steps:
        break
```

Comment: Ah, so simple. Going to play around with this a bit and see if I have any other questions.